# Appending to an object inside of list in HOCON

Tags: list, object, merge, config, hocon

I have difficulty appending an object to an object that is inside of the list.
In one file I have two objects specified.

```
`ObjectOne = {
value1= 12
value2 = 15}

ObjectTwo = {
value1= 10
value2 = 7}`
```

In other file I have a list that has objects inside of it. Something like this:

```
`List = [
{
value3='abc'
value4='456'}
{
value3='bcd'
value4='456'
}
]`
```

I would need to append to the objects inside of the list so the value1 and value2 are on the same level as value3 and 4.

So far I have tried this:

```
`List = [
${ObjectOne}{
value3='abc'
value4='456'
}
${ObjectTwo}{
value3='bcd'
value4='456
}
]`
```

or

```
`List = [{
   value3='abc'
   value4='456'
   }+=${ObjectOne}
{
value3='bcd'
value4='456
}+=${ObjectTwo}
]`
```

Both with no luck, have you ever faced similar issue?